# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 inside VMWare

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 12.10, vmware

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 inside VMWare workstation 8.  Once installing the tools started, it got stuck with a message saying:

```
Installing VMware Tools. Please Wait...
```

How do I get it to boot? I have left it sitting for at least half an hour before restarting it.

This was originally asked re. 12.04. I am having the same problem with 12.10. I suspect it's some interaction between VMware and my corporate firewall, but I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Can you try install the OS using VirtualBox, for example? And on other computer? If yes, it can help us to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This now works for me in 12.10. First I configured my corporate firewall to let VMware Workstation get through when I was prompted for my credentials. Today I updated to 8.0.4 build-744019. I created a new VM and the install completed in about 15 minutes, including VMware Tools. For 12.04 try again either outside your firewall or with your firewall configured before you start the install. And use 8.0.4 build-744019 or newer.